# jquery multible dialog box in form

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog

I have a problem with the Jquery Dialog box,

I use a function to create same dialog box for different days and I call the function with clicking on a button for each day. This buttons are located in a table which is in the form.

As soon as the buttons are clicked, the form is submitted. Page is load again. here is the code:

```
function on_create_form_clicked(tag){    
    var i=1;

    var html =
        "<div id=divparent"+i+">" +
        "PauseVon:" + "<br>"+"PauseBis:" +
        "<p>"+"<input type='text' readonly='readonly' class='MoP1A'/>"+"&nbsp;"+"<input type='text' readonly='readonly' class='MoP1E'/>"+"</p>" +
        "<button class='ok'>ok</button>" +
        "<button class='add'>add</button>" + 
        "<button class='remove'>remove</button><br>" + 
        "</div>";

    var div = $(html);

    var default_MoP1A = $('#'+tag+'P1A').val();
    div.find('.'+tag+'P1A').val(default_MoP1A);        

    var default_MoP1E = $('#'+tag+'P1E').val();
    div.find('.'+tag+'P1E').val(default_MoP1E);

    div.find(".add").click(function() {
        i++;

        var id1=tag+'P'+i+'A';
        var id2=tag+'P'+i+'E';
        var id3=tag+'PVon'+i;
        var id4=tag+'PBis'+i;

        $("<label for="+id1+" id="+id3+">PauseVon"+i+"</label>"+"&nbsp;"+"<input type='text' id="+id1+"/><br>"+"&nbsp;"+"<label for="+id2+" id="+id4+">PauseBis"+i+"</label>"+"&nbsp;"+"<input type='text' id="+id2+"/><br>").appendTo("#divparent");

        $("#"+tag+'P'+i+'A').timeEntry();
        $("#"+tag+'P'+i+'E').timeEntry();
    });

    div.find(".remove").click(function() {
        $("#"+tag+'P'+i+'E').remove();
        $("#"+tag+'PBis'+i).remove();
        $("#"+tag+"PVon"+i).remove();
        $("#"+tag+'P'+i+'A').remove();

        i=i-1;
    });

    div.find('.ok').click(function()
                          {

                              div.dialog('close');
                              $("#'divparent'"+i+"").remove();

                              window[tag+'P'+i+'A']= div.find('.'+tag+'P1A').val();
                              window[tag+'P'+i+'E'] = div.find('.'+tag+'P1E').val();

                          });

    $('form#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // $("form#form).html($("input#PauseVon2").val());
        //$('#divparent').dialog('open');
    });

    div.dialog(
        {
            title:"Enter PauseVon and PauseBis",
            close: destroy_this_dialog
        });}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all your code, but I suspect the problem is that you're binding `$('form#form').submit()` inside the click handler. You should bind it in when the page is loaded.

Comment: unfortunately, than the buttons doesn't work at all...

Comment: "destroy_this_dialog" seems like the problem... after removing it pops up. but why?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?